# Python New Line confusion in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have the following Python code. It reads a csv file and outputs the first column to a new csv file.

But the problem is in my csv file there is \n apart from new lines for creating new rows. But they are wrapped within a double quote.

For instance like this:

```
A, B, C,
D, "12
34", E,
F, G, H
```

So I think i need to add quotechar='"' somewhere but I couldnt figure it out.

```
f_in = open('source.csv')

fields = []

for line in f_in.readlines():
    fields.append([item.strip('\n') for item in line.split(',')])
f_in.close()

f_out = open('sourceNew.csv', 'w')

for i in range(len(fields)):
    if fields[i][0] != '':
        f_out.write(fields[i][0] + ',,\n')


f_out.close()
```

How can i distinguish the real new row \n and \n wrapped in a double quote.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Python CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

records = []
reader = csv.reader(open('source.csv', 'rb'))

for record in reader:
    print record
    records.append(record)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Lafada, thanks for the edit. A proper hyperlink looks better.

Comment: Using the questions input and this script the output is 4 seperate arrays unless I'm missing something...
    ['A', ' B', ' C', '']
    ['D', ' "12']
    ['34"', ' E', '']
    ['F', ' G', ' H']

Comment: Using `csv.reader (open('source.csv'), quotechar='"')`, with quotechar specified helps. See the OPs answer with full code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did,

```
import csv

f_in  = csv.reader (open('source.csv'), quotechar='"')

fields = []

for line in f_in:
    fields.append(line)

f_out = open('sourceNew.csv', 'w')

for i in range(len(fields)):
    if fields[i][0] != '':
        f_out.write(fields[i][0] + ',,\n')


f_out.close()import csv

f_in  = csv.reader (open('source.csv'), quotechar='"')

fields = []

for line in f_in:
    fields.append(line)

f_out = open('sourceNew.csv', 'w')

for i in range(len(fields)):
    if fields[i][0] != '':
        f_out.write(fields[i][0] + ',,\n')


f_out.close()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is with python 3 would be to use `newline=''`. As you can see from the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and examples. They consistently use `newline=''` when opening the file.

```py
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
```

From the Footnotes

> [1]   (1, 2) If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.